# How to manage large amount content on one page in a clean user searchable way, filters

Tags: database, wordpress, filter, content-management-system

I've presented them all as a list in 3 columns (see here: http://focallocal.org/action/ ) but i need to double the amount there now and it is going to look terrible.

what we really need is filters to cross reference and organize them as the number will grow to over 100 soon. Any suggestions for managing and organizing the large amount of content?

It doesn't have to be on one page as long as i can put a short intro and photo to each page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest making a separate post for each of your project descriptions with a custom post type called "project" or similar to group them all (and so it doesn't affect any ordinary blog posts.)

[How to add a custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types)

Next, you need to "flush" the permalinks (Settings > Permalinks, click *Save Changes*.)

The Project posts can be split into [categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Category) or you can add [tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Tag) (less formal) and each post can have a featured image.

If you called your post type "project", you will be able to view an index of all of them at http://example.com/project, which, taking the TwentyFourteen theme as an example, will use the `archive.php` file as a template (see the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).)